# Perturbing a tensorial expression

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion, tensors, vector-calculus, asymptotics

I am new to Mathematica. I am trying to simplify an expression of the some form like:

$$
n_i \sigma_{ij} n_j - \gamma n_i \hat{\sigma_{ij}} n_j = 2 + v_i x_i + \kappa E_{ij} \chi_{ji} 
$$

There are more terms, but in general I have expressions involving tensors upto rank 4 in a 3-D flat space and I need to perturb it in terms of $\epsilon$ and then collect terms.

What is the best way to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your equation has only a term linear in epsilon. Therefore it is already linear in the perturbation.

Comment: @DanielHuber yeah my bad, I meant all the tensor $E_{ij}$ ,$\chi _{ij}$, $\sigma$ can be perturbed in terms of epsilon

Comment: Maybe `Series[expr /. x -> x + eps, {eps, 0, 2}]`, adjusting the order as needed. See also `SeriesCoefficient`.